# how to forward users to "resetPassword" page if users attempt to login more then 3 times with invalid username & password(STRUTS2)

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor

I want to implement:

If users tries to login with invalid username & password  for more than 3 times. I would like to forward them to my "reset password page".

What is the logic behind this. I'm unable to catch the exact logic for this problem. Please help.

What I thought to apply:
 passing default value from my form textfield as `Login_attempt=1` from my form ,

```
//geter & setter of loginAttempt
if(loginAttempt>3)
{
    return resetPassword;//forwarding to resetPassword.jsp from my struts.xml
} 
else
{    
    //perform other tasks
}
```

But from my above logic I have doubt : How can I increment the `loginAttempt` value on each time of the form submits. so that my above code will work for me.

If you have any other logic to implement. Please share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing that as you want would become a security hole, as the number of attempts would be part of the html, so anyone could change it (you don't need special tools, you can do that with chrome dev tools for example). So with this in mind some malicious user could make a program to have infinite attempts to try a brute force attack.

To avoid this security gap you may use one of the following approaches:

- Store the number of attempts in the session. In my opinion this is the easiest way given that you're using Struts2 as your framework.
  To get the session in your Struts2 Action you should implement the [SessionAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) interface.
  Also, don't forget to reset the value of the attempts once the user has logged in successfuly.
- Some developers don't like using the session so they use a database. This is a better approach than the session in terms of performance, specially if your website has a high number of users.
- Another option would be using the cookies or even a hidden parameter in a form but encrypting it's information (the first one is the aproach of the Ruby on Rails framework for example).

The best choice depends on your project's requirements. In my own opinion you shouldn't use the last option unless you are using some framework or tool that gives support for it.

To chose between the other two options a good indicator would be the amount of users you expect your website will have (if you have few or you're doing a private website the session may be a better aproach. The database is always fine but the development time needed is usually higher and it might be a little more harmful for maintainability).

Of course there are many more solutions for this but I think I have covered the most common.

Comment: Thanks but i do now want to use the seesion for this purpose

Comment: it will be not pass as parameter. i will create getter & setter into my action class. and it will be not shown in the users browser. So it will not became a security hole.

Comment: It will be part of the html, so anyone can change it (you don't need special tools, you can do that with chrome dev tools for example). So with this in mind some malicious user could make a program to have infinite attempts to try a brute force attack. Of course it all depends on your requirements, but doing it that way IS a security hole.

Comment: so what should i do to avoid this security hole?

Comment: There are several approaches. As I said, using the session would be the easiest way. Some developers don't like using the session so they use a database... Other solution would be using the cookies or even a hidden parameter in a form but encrypting it's information (this is the aproach of the Ruby on Rails framework for example).

Comment: @admenva   i am going to give try as you said in session way.... Can you explain it in detail? How to implement this. `As I said, using the session would be the easiest way.`

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Why don't you want to use the session? It's far and away the best solution, and allows the user to try again by closing down the browser and opening it again. I don't understand what the difficult in implementation is--for every failed login increment a counter, and once it hits whatever limit you want, do something different.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay i will use session mechanism. no i am going to implement this. Can you tell me when shall i clear the login_attempt value from the session?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Whenever you want, probably during the "sending them to the reset password page" or after an action taken on that page.

Comment: @DaveNewton is right. Implementing this with the session is no more than incrementing a counter and then reset it when you do the redirect or the user logs in. To get the session in your action you should implement the [SessionAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html) interface as I said in the answer.

Comment: @admenva I'll +1 your answer now, but i suggest you to edit it with all the possibilities included in the comments (database, session with a oneliner example, etc)

Comment: @admenva Feeling very difficult to implement to do this with session. My application have daily 5000 users visitors.   I thought to do with session like: 'My Logic->  when users attempt for first time then a dynamic list will be created with the name of  userId, and at the same time usersId & his attempt counter will be inserted. Before creating this list i will check 'if listName(by userId) exists then update its attempt by (lastAttempt+1) if does not exists then create dynamic list.     But i am unable to implement this using session mechanism. What you say! What you suggest for my mind?

Comment: @DaveNewton  Feeling very difficult to implement to do this with session. My application have daily 5000 users visitors.   I thought to do with session like: **My Logic->**when users attempt for first time then a dynamic list will be created with the name of  userId, and at the same time usersId & his attempt counter will be inserted. Before creating this list i will check 'if listName(by userId)exists then update its attempt by (lastAttempt+1) if does not exists then create dynamic list.     But i am unable to implement this using session mechanism. What you say! What you suggest for my mind?

Comment: @ashutoshsingh Huh? Each user has their own session, just put a counter in it.

Comment: As Dave Newton has said each user has a session, so you don't have to worry of all that stuff, you just add a value to it and it is magicaly stored for that particular user.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please check my above code. i tried two-two times. But stile i am unable to solve this problem. Please help

Comment: @ashutoshsingh This should not be done in an interceptor, rather in the login actin. All you need to do is increment a counter, check its value, and redirect appropriately.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I tried alot. Again i tried please  check my new update (above). My new try  is also not working. I tried to write it same as you said  :-  `All you need to do is increment a counter, check its value, `   But i don't where i am doing mistake.

Comment: @admenva Thankyou for the info. Finally i did it with session

Answer (score 1):

To roughly answer your new question, completely untested:

```java
public class LoginAction {
    // Getters, setters, password checking, utils, etc. elided.

    public String execute() {
        return tooManyAttempts(password) ? RESET_PASSWORD : SUCCESS;
    }

    public boolean tooManyAttempts(String password) {
        Integer attempts = default(session.get(LOGIN_ATTEMPTS), 0);
        attempts = passwordCorrect() ? 0 : attempts + 1;
        session.put(LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, attempts);
        return attempts > 3;
    }
}
```

Your code is a little difficult to read.

Comment: `default(session.get(LOGIN_ATTEMPTS), 0);` what it mean? i think this means intially you are intializing `LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` with 0 .  But i keep this same line. Its giving me error       ERRORS are : `Syntax error on token "default", invalid Name`

Comment: @ashutosh ... Because you probably don't have a "default" function. I would hope you'd understand that much and be able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: yeah that is a method for handling session_login attempts value.

Comment: i made a new method but i am getting "null pointer exception" with my new method . Why is it so? (my code is above)

Comment: @Ashutosh How should I know, you don't even say where it is. I'm suspicious of using both `LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` and `"LOGIN_ATTEMPTS"`--in my code that's a session object key, not the counter itself.

Comment: it is there in my above code. I updated this question above with new try.Please check it. There i made a new method for handling this session object `LOGIN_ATTEMPTS` but my new method is giving me null pointer exception.

Comment: @Ashutosh I don't even know what's null. There is no possible way this can be that difficult.

Comment: From this line `Integer attempts = default(session.get(LOGIN_ATTEMPTS), 0);`  . What should i perform with this method `default(session.get(LOGIN_ATTEMPTS), 0)`   ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21868/discussion-between-dave-newton-and-ashutosh)

Comment: @ashutosh You should get a 0 or the current attempt count. It'll needed a cast.

Comment: `It'll needed a cast` in which case i will need cast?

Comment: @Ashutosh The session stores objects. You need an Integer. I think you should take a step back; you're in way over your head-IMO you herded a stronger background in basic Java and development before trying to tackle this.

Comment: @ashutosh Hence getting a default value of zero if it's null.

Comment: no i am not getting zero. i am getting null  .NOTE: i have define my session as `Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();`

Comment: @ashutosh THATS WHY YOU GIVE IT A DEFAULT OF ZERO IF IT'S NULL. This is trivial; again, you're in over your head. Learn the basics before proceeding *any* further.

Comment: @Ashutosh it turns out I don't know which books you have, so I guess I don't know.